# Possible to use a running total row in powerpivot for calculation in a calculated field?

Tags: excel, powerpivot

If I have a pivot table and I set the row to be a running total according to date and right now i will like to use this row to create a calculated field. Is it possible?

If not then is there a formula for cumulative calculations for calculated field?

Will supply more examples if need more clarification.

I want to do something like this

week    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
count   20  20  21  25  26  27  28  29  21  21
cumulative count    20  40  61  86  112 139 167 196 217 238

If the week is the base field then can I create a calculated field that does something like the cumulative count? I am doing this as i need to use the cumulative count for further calculations and if i use the show values as running total it seems to me that I cant use that variable for further calculations.

Hope this helps to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are time intelligence functions built into DAX. You could use TOTALYTD(), TOTALQTD(), and TOTALMTD() if you have a proper date dimension with contiguous, non-repeating dates ranging from January 1 in the first year you have data through December 31 in the last year you have data.

If you have a non-standard fiscal calendar you can get the same effect so long as you have index fields for each time granularity of interest which are increasing over time.

```
CustomTotalYTD:=
CALCULATE(
    [<some measure>]
    ,FILTER(
        ALL( 'DimDate' )
        ,'DimDate'[FiscalYear] = MAX( 'DimDate'[FiscalYear] )
            && 'DimDate'[Date] <= MAX( 'DimDate'[Date] )
    )
)
```

Comment: so its to create a calculated field that is like a cumulative running total then later can use the calculated field for further calculations?

Comment: Yes, you'd define as a measure in Power Pivot one of the TOTAL*TD() or a custom version based on a fiscal calendar hierarchy similar to the example I gave.

Comment: Sorry am a newbie to Excel but if my baseline field is a week number and all like what i updated above then how do can i create the calculated field with the week number as the DimDate replacement?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but I just realized that I am using another calculated field to and I can't put that in as a measure. sigh. its driving me crazy

Comment: then is there anyway of calculating a running total of a calculated field? This is the error excel gives me. "Calculation error in measure 'Date'[cumu of cumu]: The SUM function only accepts a column reference as the argument number 1."

Comment: No need to SUM(). Just put the existing measure into the CALCULATE() sample I provided.